# RawQueryset isn't working. ProgrammingError-"Error binding parameter 1: type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not supported"

Tags: python, django

views.py -

```
if product.variant != "None":
    variants = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=product.id)
    colors = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=product.id, size_id=variants[0].size_id)
    sizes = Variants.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM core_variants WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY size_id",[id])
    variant = Variants.objects.get(id=variants[0].id)
context = {'sizes': sizes,
            'colors': colors,
            'variant': variant,
          }

return render(request, 'core/product-details.html', context)
```

product-details.html -

```
<select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
    {% for rs in sizes %}
    <option {% if variant.size_id == rs.size_id %}selected{% endif %} value="{{rs.size_id}}">{{rs.size_id.title}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The error i'm getting is "**Error binding parameter 1: type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not supported**"

The line i'm getting error is "**{% for rs in sizes %}**"

I just want to show all the options from the queryset

Comment: Why o you use a raw query?

Comment: Can you share the related models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `[id]`, but [**`id(…)`** <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a builtin function to get the "identity" of an object. You thus can use `product.id`:

```
if product.variant is not None:
    variants = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=product.id)
    colors = Variants.objects.filter(
        product_id=product.id, size_id=variants[0].size_id
    )
    sizes = Variants.objects.raw(
        'SELECT * FROM core_variants WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY size_id',
        [product.id],
    )
    variant = Variants.objects.get(id=variants[0].id)
context = {
    'sizes': sizes,
    'colors': colors,
    'variant': variant,
}

return render(request, 'core/product-details.html', context)
```

But it makes not much sense to write raw queries for this, nor to make two queries to get the `Variant`s.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot brother you saved my time. 
And the reason to write the raw query is that I couldn't use distinct() or values() here because I wanted the whole query so I thought that is the only way to do that.